# Distinct Binary Heaps

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees, recursion, heaps

I have $n$ elements out of $n-1$ are distinct. The repeated element is either minimum or maximum element. I need to figure out how many distinct max heaps can be made from it.

*My analysis* : I started with $n$ distinct elements. Since root is fixed( maximum element) we can choose $l$(found using deducting total elements from elements in penultimate level) from remaining $n-1$ elements and recursively choose for Left Sub-tree and Right Sub-tree.

Recurrence Relation :

> $T(n)={n-1 \choose l} * T(l) * T(r)$

Now for $n-1$ distinct elements(given), for root we have $2$ options i.e. maximum elements and we can recurse as above for left and right sub-tree. But since the repeated element is also there I am not able to figure out exact way to do so.

Eg: $A=[2,6,6] =>$
There are 2 distinct max heaps $ => [6,2,6] , [6,6,2]$

I am unable to think of the way to find out the number of max heaps in this case. Can someone think of algorithm/recurrence relation to find so ?

Comment: Why is there 2 distinct heap for [2,6,6]? Max heap is [6,2,6] and [6,6,2] while min heap is [2, 6, 6] and the answer should be 3?

Comment: @ChristopherBoo Sorry, I forgot to mention we can make max heaps only. I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the duplicate element is the maximum element, the answer is the same as when all numbers are distinct. Let's say the duplicate element is $a_1, a_2$. Even though they are the same, we can treat it as $a_1 > a_2$, and then remove the duplicate heaps where the only difference is the exchange of $a_1, a_2$, but that is not possible because $a_1$ is always at the root. So no duplicates found.

If the duplicate element is the minimum element, the problem gets more interesting. Let $S(n)$ be the number of max heaps such that the minimum element is duplicated, and $T(n)$ be the number of max heaps such that there are no duplicates. We already know that

$$T(n) = {{n-1}\choose {l}} \times T(l) \times T(r)$$

with base case $T(1) = 1$.

For the duplicate case, we have 3 cases. We can put them both into the left subtree, both into the right subtree, or one in each subtree. Hence, the recursion is

$$S(n) = {{n-3}\choose {l-2}} S(l) T(r) + {{n-3}\choose {r-2}} T(l) S(r) + {{n-3}\choose {l-1}} T(l) T(r)$$

with base case $S(1) = 0, S(2) = 1, S(3) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks I got it now. Also in the duplicate case, is the finding the value of $l,r $ for $S(l),S(r)$ same as finding the value of $l,r$ for $T(l),T(r)$. If not so, could you elaborate on it a little bit ?

Comment: I believe it is the same. The size of the left/right heap shouldn't change just because there's a duplicate. Also, if it helped you, can you mark my answer as accepted :P

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you !